# Nosetests and finding out all possible library functions

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, nose

I have recently been getting back into python and I am a bit rusty. I have started working with the testing framework nose. I am trying to find out what possible functions I have available for use with this framework.

For example when I used rspec in ruby if I wanted to find out what "options" I have available when writing a test case I would simply go to the link below and browse the doco until I found what I needed:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/comparison-matchers

Now when I try and do the same for nose, Google keeps sending me to:

https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-functions

Although the doco is informative it's not really what I'm looking for.

Is there a python command I can use to find possible testing options or another place where good up to date documentation is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the assertions nose/unittests provides should be documented:

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html

In addition to doc, the code will always tell the truth.  You could check out the library source code, or drop into a debugger inside your test method:

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

And then inspect the test method for available assertions.

`dir(self)`

`help(unittest.skip)`

Comment: Thanks mate very useful answer, found what I was looking for :)